# Doesn't fstream support dynamic creation of files

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I'm trying to create files dynamically and it seems like there is no way with fstream. Is there actually any?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

for (int i = 0; i<2; ++i){
 std::ofstream outfile
 outfile.open ((char)i+"sample_file.txt"); // something like this. numbers appended to the filename
 outfile << i;
 outfile.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: `(char)i+"sample_file.txt"` is not doing what you think it is.  This is C++ not Java/C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean with a name created at run time, then yes, but you have to build your name in a valid way. E.g. (after `#include <sstream>`):

```
std::ostringstream fname;
fname << "sample_file_" << i << ".txt";

outfile.open(fname.str().c_str());
```